# Selecting "either representative" Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A Chess club consisting of $14$ Math majors, $11$ EE majors and $11$ CS majors. In how many ways can the club select a president and vice president *if either the president or the vice president must be a CS major*?

Given solution: $P(36,2) - P(25,2) = 660$

---

### I am trying to understand this:

Given:

- $14$ Math majors
- $11$ EE
- $11$ CS

So this is a total: $36$ students

"if either the president or the vice president must be a CS major"

**Which means I must combine $2$ possible outcomes:**

**$1.$ Outcome A:**

> - President: Not a CS major, so must be Math or EE: $14$ Math + $11$ EE = $25$
>
>   - must select $1 = P(25,1)$
> - Vice President: A CS Major: $11$ CS
>
>   - must select $1 = P(11,1)$
>
> Thus outcome A $= P(25,1) \cdot P(11,1)$

**$2.$ Outcome B:**

> - President: A CS Major: $11$ CS
>
>   - must select $1 = P(11,1)$
> - Vice President: Not a CS major, so must be Math or EE: $14$ Math + $11$ EE $= 25$
>
>   - must select $1 = P(25,1)$
>
> Thus outcome B = $P(11,1) \cdot P(25,1)$

**Combining both outcomes** for the final solution to the problem would yield: 
    $$2 \cdot [P(11,1) \cdot P(25,1)] = 550$$

---

### Why is my solution incorrect? How can I break this problem down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is incorrect because you forgot to count the cases in which *both* officers are CS majors: that can happen in $P(11,2)=110$ ways, which accounts perfectly for the difference between your answer and the given solution.

The given solution is a bit more efficient, though: it counts the total number of ways of choosing the officers without regard to the restriction and then subtracts the ways that are not allowed. That is, there are $P(36,2)$ ways to choose the two officers if we ignore the requirement that at least one be a CS major. However, $P(25,2)$ of these ways give us two officers who are not CS majors, so we have to throw those out, leaving $P(36,2)-P(25,2)$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I have up-voted your answer and accepted your solution.

Comment: @lucidgold: You’re welcome; glad to help.